# Fragment cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Executor error

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, fragment

I'm attempting to sign in or sign up using fragments, and after a successful sign-in/sign up, the `HomeActivity` supposed to load. The issue is that when I click the sign-in/sign up button, it returns to the same fragment instead of going to the `HomeActivity.class`. The app's initialization page is called LoginRegistrationActivity.class where it will call the `SignIn` fragment. I confirmed that Sign in/Sign Up is working well, but I am unable to navigate to the `HomeActivity.class` after successful authentication. I'm not sure if there is an issue with the AndroidManifest.xml file.

I got this logcat error after I clicked sign in:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fyp.selfzen.fragments.O_LoginRegistration.SignIn cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Executor
> at com.fyp.selfzen.fragments.O_LoginRegistration.SignIn.login(SignIn.java:124)
> at com.fyp.selfzen.fragments.O_LoginRegistration.SignIn$1.onClick(SignIn.java:87)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
> at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

SignIn.java fragment

```
public class SignIn extends Fragment{
    private EditText editText_email, editText_password;
    private String email, password;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

LoginRegisrationActivity loginRegistration;

public SignIn(LoginRegisrationActivity loginRegistration) {
    this.loginRegistration = loginRegistration;
}

public static SignIn newInstance(LoginRegisrationActivity loginRegistration) {
    SignIn fragment = new SignIn(loginRegistration);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    editText_email = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_email_login_activity);
    editText_password = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_password_login_activity);
    TextView button_login = view.findViewById(R.id.button_login_activity);
    TextView textView_signup_login = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_signup_login);
    final SmoothCheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_login_activity);
    checkBox.setChecked(false);


    button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            email = editText_email.getText().toString();
            password = editText_password.getText().toString();

            editText_email.clearFocus();
            editText_password.clearFocus();

            login(email, password);
        }
    });

    textView_signup_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SignUp f2 = SignUp.newInstance(loginRegistration);
            loginRegistration.loadFrag(f2, getResources().getString(R.string.regis));
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void login(String email, String password) {

    editText_email.setError(null);
    editText_password.setError(null);

    if (!isValidMail(email) || email.isEmpty()) {
        editText_email.requestFocus();
        editText_email.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.please_enter_email));
    }
    else if(password.isEmpty()){
        editText_password.requestFocus();
        editText_password.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.please_enter_password));
    }
    else {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successfully sign in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  // Intent i = new Intent(loginRegistration, HomeActivity.class); //First try to go to HomeActivity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), HomeActivity.class); //Second try 
                    startActivity(i);
                    //loginRegistration.finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } //onComplete
        }); // firebaseAuth
    }// else
} // login end
}
```

SignUp.java fragments

```
public class SignUp extends Fragment{
    private EditText editText_name, editText_email, editText_password, editText_phoneNo;
    private String name, email, password, phoneNo;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

LoginRegisrationActivity loginRegistration;

public SignUp(LoginRegisrationActivity loginRegistration) {
    this.loginRegistration = loginRegistration;
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static SignUp newInstance(LoginRegisrationActivity loginRegistration) {
    SignUp fragment = new SignUp(loginRegistration);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registration, container, false);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    editText_name = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_name_register);
    editText_email = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_email_register);
    editText_password = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_password_register);
    editText_phoneNo = view.findViewById(R.id.editText_phoneNo_register);
    TextView button_submit = view.findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
    TextView textView_login = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_login_register);


    // Go to login page
    textView_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SignIn f1 = SignIn.newInstance(loginRegistration);
            loginRegistration.loadFrag(f1, getResources().getString(R.string.login));
        }
    });


    button_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            name = editText_name.getText().toString();
            email = editText_email.getText().toString();
            password = editText_password.getText().toString();
            phoneNo = editText_phoneNo.getText().toString();

            form();
        }
    });
    return view;
}


private boolean isValidMail(String email) {
    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}

public void form() {

    editText_name.setError(null);
    editText_email.setError(null);
    editText_password.setError(null);
    editText_phoneNo.setError(null);

    if (name.equals("") || name.isEmpty()) {
        editText_name.requestFocus();
        editText_name.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.please_enter_name));
    }
    else if (!isValidMail(email) || email.isEmpty()) {
        editText_email.requestFocus();
        editText_email.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.please_enter_email));
    }
    else if (password.equals("") || password.isEmpty()) {
        editText_password.requestFocus();
        editText_password.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.please_enter_password));
    }
    else if (phoneNo.equals("") || phoneNo.isEmpty()) {
        editText_phoneNo.requestFocus();
        editText_phoneNo.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.please_enter_phone));
    }
    else {
        editText_name.clearFocus();
        editText_email.clearFocus();
        editText_password.clearFocus();
        editText_phoneNo.clearFocus();
    }
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successfully registered!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Intent i = new Intent(loginRegistration, HomeActivity.class);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                //loginRegistration.finish();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Sign up failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
} // end of form
}
```

LoginRegistrationActivity.class

```
public class LoginRegisrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String curent;
    VideoView vide;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_regisration);

        vide = findViewById(R.id.vide);
        String video_url = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.login_video;
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(video_url);
        vide.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        vide.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                vide.requestFocus();
                vide.start();
            }
        });

        SignIn f1 = SignIn.newInstance(this);
        loadFrag(f1, getResources().getString(R.string.login));    
    }


    public void loadFrag(Fragment f1, String name) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if(!name.equals(curent)){
            curent =name;
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout, f1, name);
        }

        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.fyp.selfzen.activities.LoginRegisrationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.fyp.selfzen.activities.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Have you solved your problem yet?

I ran into a similar but different issue when trying to use Fragments with FirebaseAuth. All of the documentation I found only referenced using Activities. Changing `.addOnCompleteListener` to `.addOnSuccessListener` and adding an `.addOnFailureListener` made my app work as expected. My app was originally crashing because of the Executor even though it would successfully authenticate users; the success/failure listeners fixed my issue.

### My original code (written with help from Firebase Docs):

```
 private void authWithFirebase(String email, String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener( (java.util.concurrent.Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                       Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successfully signed in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        FragmentFactory.startAdminFragment((MainActivity) getActivity());
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText( getContext(), "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            });
}
```

### Current/Working code:

```
private void authWithFirebase(String email, String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                    FragmentFactory.startAdminFragment((MainActivity) getActivity());
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure");
                    Toast.makeText( getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            } );
}
```

### Note:

I only have 1 Activity so I was able to login and continue to my desired Fragment but you should be able to modify my code (`FragmentFactory.startAdminFragment((MainActivity) getActivity());`) to continue to your `HomeActivity.class`

This video helped a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPhy1PKR1Wg
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In **SignIn.java** and **SignUp.java** fragment you add addOnCompleteListener() for firebaseAuth. So, pass arguments in it,

**Instead of,**

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {}
```

**To,**

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(getContext(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {}
```

IF, **getContext()** not work then try to write **getActivity()**.

Comment: Hi! I just update my code to `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()`. I just removed the `(Executor) this,`. However after successful sign in/sign up, I',m still redirected back to the sign page.

Comment: when you click on sign in button then which toast you are getting exactly. "Successfully registered!" or "Sign up failed" ? If you are not able to see toast then just print in your log and check.

Comment: "Successfully registered!" is display then the sign in page is display again.

Comment: I tried to use a different class other than the `HomeActivity.class` to load, but I got still the same results. It loads back to sign-in page.

Comment: Did you debug ?? In which line you got error?? and can post your home activity?

Comment: From the logcat the error points to the intent part `Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i)`

Comment: The `HomeActivity` got >3000 lines of codes, should I share it here?